# Markov chains, hitting times and expected number of passages

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, self-learning

> Let $X_n, n\geq1$ be a Markov chain with state space $\{1,\dots,6\}$ and transition matrix
> $$
> P = \left[
> \begin{array} \\
> 0 & 0  & 1-\alpha & \alpha & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 0        &    0   & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 0        &     1  & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0  & 0        &   0    & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0  & 0        &    0   & 0 & 1 \\
> 0 & 0  & 1-\alpha &      0 & \alpha & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right]
> $$
>
> Find $\rho_{xy}=P(T_y<\infty| X_0=x)$ and $G(x,y)=\mathbb{E}[N(y)|X_0=x]$ such that $T_y$ is the first passage time and $N(y)$ is the number of visits to state $y$.

Clearly states $\{1,3,4\}$ are recurrent and states $\{2,5,6\}$ are transient. So for the first set $G(x,y)=\infty$

We know that the following holds
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{xy} &= P(T_y<\infty| X_0=x) \\
          &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(T_y=n| X_0=x)  \\ 
\\
G(x,y) &=\mathbb{E}[N(y)|X_0=x]\\
       &=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}I\{X_n=y\}|X_0=x] \\
       &=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(x,y)
\end{align}
$$
such that $P^n$ is the n-step ahead transition function. Taking for example $x=5,y=5$,
$$
\begin{align}
\rho_{55} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(T_5=n| X_0=5) \\
G(5,5)    &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P^n(5,5)
\end{align}
$$
We may notice that we have only one way back from $5$ into $5$, $5\to 6\to 5$ and thus we have zero probabilities for reaching 5 in even number of steps thus

$$G(5,5) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}P^{2k}(5,5) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha^k = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}$$

However, if I find $\rho_{xy}$ through the system of equations,
$$
\rho_{ij}=P(i,j)+\sum_{z\neq j}P(i,z)\rho_{z,j}
$$
and apply the theorem that says that for transient states $G(x,y)=\rho_{xy}/(1-\rho_{yy})$, I get $\rho_{55}=\rho_{66}=\rho_{65}=\alpha$, $\rho_{56}=1$ and $G(5,5)=\alpha/(1-\alpha)$ as the result.

What am i doing wrong?

I would appreciate any insights.